# Prettytable 0.7.2 HTML Table Not Working

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I am trying to get Prettytable 0.7.2 working with an HTML table. I just can't seem to get it working. I am using the following:

```
from prettytable import from_html
html = "<table><tr><th>h1</th></tr><tr><td>v1</td></tr></table>"
table = from_html(html)
print (table)
```

Which results in:

```
[<prettytable.PrettyTable object at 0x90556ec>]
```

I can get the table to work using the other methods, but I can't seem to tackle the HTML table method. I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong or missing something. If anyone could shed some light on this issue it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, `table` isn't a PrettyTable object, but [a list containing a single PrettyTable object](http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/wiki/Tutorial#Building_from_HTML_code).

Calling the `from_html` function will return a list containing one PrettyTable per `table` tag encountered in your html string.

You want to do:

```
print table[0]
```

Which returns:

```
+----+
| h1 |
+----+
| v1 |
+----+
```